# IIB: INSERT INTO Oracle Database "¿" (inverted question marks) and chinese characters

Tags: oracle, odbc, ibm-integration-bus, embedded-sql

I am a greenhorn in Oracle Database and IBM Integration Bus and I'm trying to use the INSERT INTO function of ESQL in the IBM Integration Bus to insert data of a CSV file.

I'm using a DFDL with ISO-8859-1 encoding to read the file. When using the debugger, the message is fine and readable in SQLPLUS and SQL Developer.

I already tried to change the `NLS_CHARARCTERSET` setting in my Oracle Database although im not really sure which encoding I need. On default it was AL32UTF8 and I tried UTF8, WE8ISO8859P1.

What I also did was changing the encoding of the DFDL and changing the ODBC driver's settings to Use Oracle NLS Settings (Default), Use Microsoft Regional Settings and Use US settings.

If I try to use the INSERT INTO command the Database returns inverted question marks or Chinese characters, which is obviously not what I want.

EDIT: 
If I hardcode the INSERT INTO values it also returns the question mark. The CSV's encoding doesn't matter. What I also found out is that the CSV file's data is displayed as null. When I hardcode the values in the INSERT INTO I get inverted question marks.

Comment: Are you able to insert the same data into the database correctly by using insert query directly without using IIB ?

Comment: What encoding did the source application use when it wrote the file?

Comment: @frabar The query works well in SQL Developer and SQL Plus. FYI it also works with passthru.

Comment: @kimbert If you mean the encoding of the CSV file. It is Windows 1250 since the input file has characters like 'ß'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple option in the IIB ODBC Driver for Oracle. Just make sure that "Enable SQL Describe Param" in the advanced tab is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If you mean the encoding of the CSV file. It is Windows 1250 since the input file has characters like 'ß'

I don't understand that statement. The use of the character 'ß' does not necessarily imply Windows 1250. Do you have any other supporting evidence for that claim?

If your claim is correct then your DFDL schema is incorrect. You cannot parse a multi-byte encoding using a single-byte decoder. So the first thing you should do is to change the 'encoding' property in the format block of your DFDL schema to "5346" (according to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRH46_3.0.0_SWS/dni_ccsids_and_char_set_names.html ).

But (and I'm sorry for repeating this, but it really matters...) CHECK that your assumption about Windows 1250 is correct. Then make sure that the encoding in the DFDL schema matches the encoding of the CSV file.